# Should I write "X and I", "X and me", "I and X", or "me and X" in a conjoined object?

Tags: conjunctions, word-order, pronouns, prepositional-phrases

A question was asked in one of my friend's interview. The question was to determine the right form from the below sentences.

> Q. Correct form of English:
>
> 1. Samuel was with Susan and I
> 2. Samuel was with Susan and me
> 3. Samuel was with I and Susan
> 4. Samuel was with me and Susan
> 5. None of these

Now I vaguely remember a rule of thumb from my school days. That is "2-3-1" i.e. where all the persons are acting in a sentence, second person comes first, then third person and it is followed by first person.

So according to this theory, `1` seems to be correct to me. Is this theory correct?

Comment: So,would you say 'Samuel was with I' ? I think not. It should be 'Samuel was with Susan and me'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your theory is correct. But that leaves us with 1) and 2).

Between I and me, we can decide like this: *I* corresponds to *we* and *me* corresponds to *us*. 'He was with us' and not 'He was with we.' So, 2) is the correct option.

Comment: +1, That being said, "me and Susan" is probably the more common form in actual usage.

Answer (score 4):

A helpful trick for determining whether to use *I* or *me* in a multi-person scenario is to take the other people out of the sentence.  If you still have a valid sentence at that point, then you have the correct pronoun.

For example, with the sentence *Samuel was with Susan and I*, you take out Susan, leaving you with the sentence *Samuel was with I*.  Hopefully you can tell immediately that this is incorrect, and therefore the initial sentence is also incorrect.  If you replace *I* with *me*, the sentence then appears correct.  Now you can add Susan back in, and you still have a correct sentence: *Samuel was with Susan and me*.

As for whether you or Susan should be mentioned first, as answered [on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48397/me-and-my-wife-or-my-wife-and-me/), it is a "rule of politeness" to put yourself last.  (But the rule of thumb that I have is 3-2-1, not 2-3-1.)

Comment: Again, this is not strictly correct.  The rules for conjoined objects can be distinguished from those for simple objects.  But from a prescriptivist point of view, this answer is acceptable, and it's *close enough* to the facts that I won't downvote it.  Language learners following this rule will be correct most of the time.

Comment: For more details from a descriptive point of view, see Thomas Grano's thesis, [*"Me and her" meets "he and I": Case, person, and linear ordering in English coordinated pronouns*](http://ling.umd.edu/~tgrano/uht.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

In "Samuel was with Susan and I." *Susan and I* is the object of the verb. As such, standard English requires you to use *me*.

The NOAD has a note about using personal pronouns.

> The correct use of personal pronouns is one of the most debated topics of English usage. *I*, *we*, *they*, *he*, and *she* are subjective personal pronouns, which means they are used as the subject of the sentence, often coming before the verb ("she lives in Paris"; "we are leaving"). *Me*, *us*, *them*, *him*, and *her*, on the other hand, are objective personal pronouns, which means that they are used as the object (i.e., they receive the action) of a verb or preposition ("John likes me"; "his father left him"; "I did it for her"). This explains why it is not correct to say "John and me went to the mall": The personal pronoun is in subject position, so it must be *I*, not *me*. Using the pronoun alone makes the incorrect use obvious: "Me went to the mall" is clearly not acceptable. This analysis also explains why it is not correct to say "he came with you and I": the personal pronoun is governed by a preposition ( with) and is therefore objective, so it must be *me*, not *I*. Again, a simple test for correctness is to use the pronoun alone: "He came with I" is clearly not acceptable.

As for the order of the objects, the preferred order is "Susan and me" but there isn't a grammar rule for that.

Comment: I think that "2-3-1 rule" is just a silly hangover from Victorian *manners, politeness*, rather than *grammar*. The fact of the matter is it bears no relation to what people *actually* say. From Google Books - [john and me](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22john+and+me%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 129K results; [me and john](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22me+and+john%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 5180K results.

Comment: In natural English, *me and John* is grammatical, even in a subject.  But the *x and I* nominative form we all learn in school is much more strictly ordered--*I and x* is much rarer.

Comment: @snailboat: Indeed. [I and John went (somewhere)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+and+john+went%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 6 results. [John and I went (there)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22john+and+I+went%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 149,000 results. We only put others first in the somewhat stylised [Myself and John went](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22myself+and+john+went%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 6 hits, vs. [John and myself went](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22John+and+myself+went%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 5830 hits.

Comment: I'll also add that the NOAD's tests aren't logically sound.  It does not follow that because a particular form must be used in a simple object (or simple subject) that it must also be used in a conjoined object (or conjoined subject).

Comment: FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica, just because 'lazy english' has become popular doesn't make it right. Would you say 'Me went to town' ? The subject is always 'I'.

Comment: @GrahamStevenson The discussion so far talks about English descriptively. In descriptive linguistics, you can't talk about something being correct or incorrect.