# When do you use I instead of me

Tags: word-usage

Which is correct: If you have any questions in advance of the meeting, please don't hesitate to contact Mark Ingrao or me.

Comment: You use _I_ when it's the subject of the sentence or clause it's in. That's all.  It's really that simple. Since it's used as a direct object of _contact_ in the example, it's not the subject, so it should not be _I_.

Comment: I suggest using 'myself' instead of the me here.

Comment: @Poison Ivy Often, but it can sound starchy. Emphasising 'Mark Ingrao' and almost reducing the last two words to a schwa works in speech.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Reducing the last two words completely to a single schwa or less  would indeed work to deflect pesky questions from the speaker onto Mark. As to substituting the reflexive pronoun *myself,* in this context I would term it not *starchy* but rather *barbarous.*

Comment: Using _myself_ in that situation is placing the reflexive on a sociolinguistic cline for pseudo-formality. Which it never volunteered for. Reflexives just distinguish between coreferential pronouns; they don't promote one of them to the nobility.

Comment: I too would often use the word "myself" when it falls last in a list of alternatives (which is also often the last word of a sentence), but use "me" when first in a list. It is the same with "yourself" (which can also be conveniently adapted as "yourselves" when referring to a plural number of people or an organisation).

Comment: The quick trick I advise people to use in similar situations is to take the other person out of the sentence and decide which is better: *I* or *me*. So in your example, would you say "...contact *me*" or "...contact *I*"?

Comment: @RobJarvis I use exactly the same rule myself (myself here is genuinely reflexive). However I've heard The Queen's neice Lady Sarah Chatto use the "for my brother and I" form on TV and I'm absolutely sure she wouldn't use "for I" which is pure West Country dialect speech and not RP at all. When someone that closely related to Her Majesty uses the aspiring middle class abomination to avoid "me and my brother" in a different context I think we're on a hiding to nothing. Just grit your teeth and accept it.

Comment: I'll grit my teeth, @BoldBen, but I don't have to accept it (even if the royals do). I'm an American--I can do that. ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I write "X and I", "X and me", "I and X", or "me and X" in a conjoined object?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10515/should-i-write-x-and-i-x-and-me-i-and-x-or-me-and-x-in-a-conjoined-ob)

Comment: @RobJarvis The thing that annoys me so much is that the pervasive error "for someone and I" arises from a snobbish reaction to the working class error "me and someone did something" without any attempt to  teach the correct form.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments *I* is the subject. Try taking the name out to decide what to do.

> If you have any questions in advance of the meeting, please don't hesitate to contact Mark Ingrao or me

becomes

> If you have any questions in advance of the meeting, please don't hesitate to contact me

which is correct. Some people would use myself instead of me perhaps because it sounds less like advertising yourself. You will also hear people in the UK using myself as a subject *Mark and myself will answer your questions* but careful speakers would avoid that.

Comment: *"careful speakers would avoid that"*  Ugh! I'm from the UK and I personally detest that! ;-)  - "myself" should only be used with a reflexive verb or as an intensifier.

Comment: *" Some people would use myself instead of me perhaps because it sounds less like advertising yourself."* IMHO  the real reason is that they don't understand the grammar and are trying to avoid making a mistake.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica you may well be right, they are doing some sort of hyper-correction and falling on the wrong side.